# coldfusion imageNew error: Unsupported Image Type

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cmyk, cfimage

I am trying to use the ImageNew function (coldfusion 8) to create an image object with a image URL link, e.g. `<cfset myImage=ImageNew(evaluate( "http://.../../1.jpg" ))>`

There are many links there and most of them are good, but for some of the image links, I got an error when I call the ImageNew function: An exception occurred while trying to read the image. javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type

Does it have something to do with the size of images? Does anybody have any idea?

Many thanks

Results: Finally, it's the CMYK/RGB issue. It seems CF8 has trouble in dealing with CMYK and CF8 doesn't support convertion from CMYK to RGB. I use ImageMagic to do the convertion.

Comment: A couple of things: First, you probably don't need the `evaluate()` ... if you post full code we can tell you whether or not you need it. Second, it probably has less to do with image size and more to do with just an invalid image file, somehow. Does it always fail on the same image file, or at seemingly random files?

Comment: I tried to open those image links in browser and they all work fine. I tried to process those images again and it still failed.

Comment: e.g. There are thousands of image links. I try to process first 100 links and majority of them are fine but some of them fail. I keep processing next 100, and the results are the same

Comment: Please update your question with examples of image URLs that don't work.

Comment: Sorry Ben, the URLs will expire shortly after I got the them.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, I have this issue sometimes.  I don't think it has anything to do with your code, coldfusion's image processing utilities either cannot process a perfectly valid image, or they choke on an image that is not up to standards.  When this happens it is typically a client uploading an image and my system throws an error.  They send me the file, I resave it out using photoshop or something like that, and poof, coldfusion likes it.

The only solution I know if this is the problem, is to use a third party image processor instread of coldfusion's built in functions.  I used to use  cfx_imagecr

http://efflare.com/products/cfx_imagecr/

But that is not the only solution out there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess it's the RGB and CYMK issue of JPG. Yes, those images are provided from a third party.